# Чтение построчно out of memory

Tags: delphi

В данном коде при обработке файла в 200 мегабайт выскакивает ошибка: out of memory. Как исправить Данную ошибку в этом коде ?

```
var
list:TStrings;
   i:integer;
 str:string;

begin
    list :=TStringList.Create;
    list.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);

    for i :=list.count-1 downto 0 do
    begin
        str :=list.Strings[i];

        while Pos(edit1.text, str) >0 do
        begin
            Delete(str, Pos(edit1.text, str), Length(edit1.text)) ;
            list.Strings[i] :=str;
        end;
    end;

    list.SaveToFile('out.txt');
    list.free;
end;
```

Comment: Процедура LoadFromFile у TStringList не поддерживает файлы большого размера. Нужно использовать другой метод чтения фала.

Comment: А можете подсказать на примере моего кода ?

Comment: По моему вам уже написали код.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Утечка памяти / out of memory (delphi)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777392/%d0%a3%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8-out-of-memory-delphi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var 
  txtIn, txtOut: TextFile;
  str: string;
begin
  AssignFile(txtIn, OpenDialog1.FileName);
  AssignFile(txtOut, ExtractFilePath(OpenDialog1.FileName) + 'tmp.txt');

  Reset(txtIn);
  Rewrite(txtOut);

  while not EOF(txtIn) do
  begin
    ReadLn(txtIn, str);
    // ...
    WriteLn(txtOut, str);
  end;

  CloseFile(txtOut);
  CloseFile(txtIn);

  // move 'tmp.txt' to OpenDialog1.FileName
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно работать через TStreamReader и TStreamWriter. При некоторых условиях скорость работы может быть больше до 3х раз, чем по-старинке с readln и writeln:

```
var
  s:string;
  reader:TStreamReader;
  writer:TStreamWriter;

begin
   reader:=TStreamReader.Create(OpenDialog1.FileName, TEncoding.ANSI); // Если нужна другая кодировка - сменить
   writer := TStreamWriter.Create('out.txt', false,TEncoding.ANSI); // если нужно дописать файл, ставим True вместо false
   while not reader.EndOfStream do
     begin
        s:=reader.ReadLine;
        // делаем, что нужно с s
        writer.WriteLine(s); 
     end;
   // не забываем закрыть оба файла:
   reader.Free;
   writer.Free;
end;
```

Если же нужно обязательно хранить все строки в памяти, стоит работать через, например, TMemoryStream или TBytesStream, но стоит помнить, что в 32-битном режиме их емкость ограничена чуть менее, чем 2 Гб, а в 64-битном режиме, если надо > 2 Гб, с ними можно нормально работать только, начиная с Delphi Tokyo, или же [делать патч](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/784534/).