# Сравнение текстовых файлов \ DelphiXE

Tags: delphi

**Суть задачи такова:** Сравнить содержимое файла **1.txt** и файла **2.txt** и сохранить в файл **3.txt** уникальные строки. То есть исключить одинаковые строки, которые есть в файлах **1.txt и 2.txt** и в файл **3.txt** записать только уникальные строки.

**Я делаю это так:**

```
    var
      i : integer;
      s1, s2 : TStrings;
    begin
      s1:= TStringList.Create;
      s2:= TStringList.Create;
      Try
        s1.LoadFromFile('1.txt'); // Загружаю текстовый файл 1
        s2.LoadFromFile('2.txt'); // Загружаю текстовый файл 1
// Тут происходит сравнение
        for i := s1.Count - 1 downto 0 do
          if s2.IndexOf(s1[i]) >= 0 Then s1.Delete(i);
// Ну и тут уникальный строки сохраняются в файл 3.txt
        s1.SaveToFile('3.txt');
      Finally
        s1.Free;
        s2.Free;
      End;
    end;
```

**Все работает но:** если файлы в **250 мегабайт** то оперативная помять, моя, полностью загружается. Ну это естественно, поскольку я загружаю- эти файлы и сравниваю их в памяти (тут, конечно, все зависит от того - сколько у кого оперативной памяти и какого размера файлы).

**Вопрос:** Подскажите, есть ли другие варианты решение этой задачи, без загрузки в память. Не обязательно что бы скорость была большущая, просто что бы не грузить в память.

Comment: Наверное только через ReadLn().

Comment: @MAX, Не подскажите как ?

Comment: Количество строк в файлах одинаково?

Comment: @Dima, К сожалению разное. Иногда, но крайне редко - бывает одинаковое.

Comment: @Татьяна Делаете через вложенные циклы. Читаете строчку в первом файла, дальше циклом ищите вхождение (через тот же ReadLn) во втором файле. Если нет совпадения, то пишите текст в  третий файл.

Comment: @MAX, Я ценю ваше стремление - помочь мне, но я еще не настолько опытная что бы разобраться как правильно через ReadLn написать. Если не сложно напишите простой вариант. Или хотя бы пример.

Comment: @Татьяна Конструкци readln — базовая конструкция Паскаля. Я могу только посоветовать хоть немного потратить времени на изучение основ языка, на котором вы хотите программировать. ;-)

Comment: Веток таких с десяток: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/789452/Чтение-построчно-out-of-memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Татьяна, можно прочитать таким образом:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FileWithText1: TextFile;
  FileWithText2: TextFile;
  OutputFile: TextFile;
  S1: String;
  S2: String;
  Arr: Array of String;
  StringCount1: Integer;
  StringCount2: Integer;
begin
  // Открываем файл для записи
  AssignFile(OutputFile, 'путь и название Вашего выходного файла');
  Rewrite(OutputFile);

  // Открываем файл для чтения
  AssignFile(FileWithText1, 'путь и название Вашего исходного файла №1');
  Reset(FileWithText1);

  // Открываем файл для чтения
  AssignFile(FileWithText2, 'путь и название Вашего исходного файла №2');
  Reset(FileWithText2);

  StringCount1 := 0;
  while not EoF(FileWithText1) do
    begin
      ReadLn(FileWithText1, S1);
      Inc(StringCount1);
    end;

  StringCount2 := 0;
  while not EoF(FileWithText2) do
    begin
      ReadLn(FileWithText2, S2);
      Inc(StringCount2);
    end;

  // Переоткрываем файлы
  Reset(FileWithText1);
  Reset(FileWithText2);

  // Убеждаемся что какой-либо файл имеет больший размер (количество строк)
  // Следовательно, используем этот "большой" файл как "эталонный" (с ним сравниваем)
  if StringCount1 >= StringCount2 then
    begin
      while not EoF(FileWithText1) do
        begin
          ReadLn(FileWithText1, S1);
          ReadLn(FileWithText2, S2);
          // Собственно, сравнение и запись в выходной файл если S1 не равно S2
          if S1 <> S2 then
            WriteLn(OutputFile, S1);
        end;
    end
  else
  if StringCount1 <= StringCount2 then
    begin
      while not EoF(FileWithText2) do
        begin
          ReadLn(FileWithText1, S1);
          ReadLn(FileWithText2, S2);
          // Собственно, сравнение и запись в выходной файл если S1 не равно S2
          if S1 <> S2 then
            WriteLn(OutputFile, S1);
        end;
    end;

  // Закроем файлы
  CloseFile(OutputFile);
  CloseFile(FileWithText1);
  CloseFile(FileWithText2);
end;
```

Комментарии даны в коде. Такой "костыльный" путь я избрал для того,чтобы суметь определить количество строк в файлах. Можно было применить вложенный цикл (как предложено в комментариях), но, признаться, я не пойму, как решить проблему с выбором "эталонного" файла - количество срок-то ведь неодинаково!

Если файл *А* имеет *10* строк, а файл *Б* имеет *20* строк, то, согласно указанной последовательности, алгоритм со вложенным циклом переберет 10 строк файла *А* и остановится (`EndOfFile`), в то время, как 10 *оставшихся* строк файла *Б* будут невостребованны (мы не сможем расценить их как уникальные, поскольку цикл уже закончился не дойдя до этих строк). Тем не менее, буду рад (учиться всегда полезно), если кто-нибудь предоставит более элегантное решение.

Протестировал на двух текстовых файлах (не более 20 строк). Разницу находит и записывает в файл корректно.

Comment: Все, я разобралась. Огромная благодарность Вам Дмитрий! Все работает как нужно именно то что я хотела.!