# Как собрать уникальные строки из двух файлов?

Tags: delphi

Мне нужно собрать уникальные строки из двух файлов и записать их в файл Rezults.txt.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FName: array of string;
  F:TextFile;
  st:string;
  s:TStringList;
  I:Integer;
begin
  SetLength(FName, 2);
  FName[0] := Edit1.Text;
  FName[1] := Edit2.Text;
  s := TStringList.Create;
  s.Sorted := true;
  s.Duplicates := dupIgnore;

  for I := Low(FName) to High(FName) do
  begin
    AssignFile(F, FName[I]);
    reset(f);
    While not EOF(f) do
    begin
      readln(F,st);
      s.Add(st);
    end;
    CloseFile(f);
  end;

  s.SaveToFile('Rezults.txt');
  s.Free;
end;
```

Comment: @Kromster, отредактировала тему и внесла изменения.

Comment: Уточните, что теперь не работает?

Comment: @Kromster, Теперь все работает.

Comment: Если все работает, то к чему вопрос?

Comment: @Kromster, Я даже и не сомневаюсь, что ваши сообщения и мнения, в мою сторону - основываются на предвзятом отношении. Ответ на вопрос дан и ПРАВИЛЬНО, пользователем Igor. Что еще Вас смущает ? Не нравится что я задаю вопросы ?. Все мы, с чего то начинали и Вы, как и я, тоже были не опытным, потом, с годами приобрели опыт и это хорошо. Но то что я, иногда, задаю Вопросы, которые Вам не нравятся, на ситуацию никак не повлияет. Выходя из этого, вы можете выражать свою критику, но не более того. Поскольку на данном ресурсе - не запрещено задавать подобные вопросы. Вот что я думаю по этому поводу.

Comment: Мои сообщения исключительно непредвзяты. Если я вижу плохой вопрос или ответ я об этом пишу. Давайте вместе с вами прочитаем текст вашего вопроса? Вы спрашиваете, как собрать уникальные строки из 2 файлов в 1 и приводите рабочий код. Я вас спрашиваю, **в чем же проблема, о чем ваш вопрос?** Вспомните, что SO создан не для того чтобы помогать лично вам, а для того, чтобы собирать базу знаний по вопросам и способам их решения. В данном вопросе вы не представили  и не описали проблему ..

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сравнение текстовых файлов \ DelphiXE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/884261/%d0%a1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-delphixe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var
  FName: array of string;
  ...
begin
  SetLength(FName, 2);
  FName[0] := Edit1.Text;   
  FName[1] := Edit2.Text;

  s := TStringList.Create;
  ...
  For I := Low(FName) to High(FName) do
  begin
    ...
```

Comment: Изменила и обновила тему но понимаю что не все. А саму константу не могу понять как назначить array[1..2] of string = ('1.txt','2.txt'); ???

Comment: @Татьяна Не надо константы. Объявите массив как переменную.

Comment: Сделала и обновила код. Но еще ошибка тут: While not EOF(f) do Код ошибки --Exception class EInOutError with message 'I/O error 6'. Process Project1.exe (3424). В чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: @Татьяна Посмотрите внимательно на код в ответе. Индексация динамических массивов начинается с нуля. P.S. Включите "Range checking" в опциях компилятора и никогда не выключайте ).

Comment: Включила и обновила код в теме, но теперь почему то не работает сравнение файлов. Просто копируются и все. Что еще может быть ?

Comment: @Татьяна Какое сравнение файлов? Куда что копируется? В коде вопроса нет сравнения файлов.

Comment: Ваш код собирает уникальные строки из двух файлов и записывает их в файл 'Rezults.txt' в сортированном виде. Это не совсем то, что Вы описываете.

Comment: Igor, Прошу меня извинить, все работает. Я просто неправильно сформулировала задачу и запуталась. Но потом взяла себя в руки и разобралась, благодаря вашим подсказкам. Как всегда, Вы на высоте! +

Comment: К сожалению, ваш ответ не отвечает на поставленный вопрос .. Возможно вам стоит обменяться контактами с Татьяной и индивидуально разбираться с ее проблемами?